# Turning on selinux causes HDMI to not work. How to resolve?

Tags: linux, selinux, hdmi

In my ubuntu setup, i've turned on selinux. However that causes the HDMI port to not work? I assume there's a policy in there that stops this, but setting selinux to permissive, the machine still exhibits the same issue. On the other hand, removing the security=selinux on the kernel command line, the issue is resolved.

How do i solve this? Is there some kind of interaction with the initrd that causes this to happen?

Comment: In order to figure out what might stop your HDMI port from working, it would be necessary to know which driver is used to run it, or at least the type of GPU the HDMI port is connected to. What are the outputs of `xrandr` and `xrandr --listproviders` commands, with SELinux enabled vs. disabled?

Comment: when i xrandr on a selinux enabled boot, it only shows entries for one monitor, with security=selinux removed from the kernel command line and hdmi working, it shows a few entries 'DP-*' & 'HDMI-*'. With security=selinux and selinux set to disabled, xrandr only shows one entry. Reading some entries from people who have experienced the same problem, it looks to me like selinux is enabled and stops hdmi binding, and all the solutions about reinstalling video drivers doesn't solve the reason, which is selinux blocks the hdmi from working during bootup.

Comment: Does your GPU need a firmware file for full functionality? In that case, the firmware file might be present but not have a proper SELinux label, which might prevent it from being loaded when SELinux is enabled. (You should use `restorecon -R /` to ensure all files are properly labeled when enabling SELinux, and recreate your initrd after that to ensure all files within initrd are also properly labeled if applicable.)

Comment: So when i remove the nomodeset keyword on the kernel commandline, hdmi seems to work, even with security=selinux. On the other hand, i've been booting up with nomodeset on the kernel command line before trying selinux, so i'm not sure why it would be an issue now. In any case, on boot selinux relabels everything and it seems to be working ok for the moment.